# Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion Problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

The setup: I bought 8 distinguishable beds for my 3 (distinguishable) bedroom apartment. I want to put at least one bed in each of my bedrooms, and all beds must be placed in a bedroom. How many ways can I place my beds in my bedrooms? The question hinted at using the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion in my answer.

I'm honestly really stuck at how I can approach this problem.

Comment: If you didn't have to put at least one bed in each bedroom, you'd have $3^8$ options. From those, subtract those that are no good because bedroom 1 is empty; also subtract those that have bedroom 2 empty; and those that have bedroom 3 empty. But now the (rather few) options that have bedrooms 1 & 2 both empty got subtracted twice, so add them back once. Likewise for those with bedrooms 1&3 empty. Likewise for those with 2 &3 empty. (Fortunately, there are no options with all three bedrooms empty, so you don't have to correct even more for those.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a picture would help you a lot.

[image]

Lets say an arrangement is valid if no bedroom is empty. To get the number of valid ways, we take all the possible ways of arranging the beds ($3^8$) and subtract the invalid ways. The invalid ways can be shown in the picture as the sum of all three circles. So by PIE, we want to calculate
$$ \text{sum of all 3 circles} - \text{ sum of intersection of all pairs of circles } + \text{ sum of intersection of all 3 circles }$$

> Now, lets compute the size of each type of area. Each circle has size $2^8$. The intersection of any two pairs of circle has size $1^8$. The intersection of all 3 circles has size $0$ (the beds have to go somewhere!). Hence, we get

> $$ \text{no. of invalid ways} = (2^8 + 2^8 + 2^8) - (1^8 + 1^8 + 1^8) + 0$$